# Improve SQL query performance to remove Order by and correlated query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below inner query inside one of my lengthy query. Is there any way to optimize it. It seems that Order by and correlated is very expensive. I am seeking for another alternative.

```
SELECT (
    Select Top 1 Column
    From ABC
    Where ABC.ID = XYZ.ID
    Order By ABC.ID DESC
)
FROM XYZ
```

Comment: Your question a bit unclear... Please provide your execution plan

Comment: Having a suitable index usually helps, but in this case it looks like you're using same column for join and order by, which means that you're just picking a random row...

Comment: Please don't over-simplify the queries you show here. A column named ID is usually the unique key for a record in a table. So do you have two tables sharing a primary key? That isn't likely. So is it `Where ABC.ID = XYZ.ID_ABC` or `Where ABC.ID_XYZ = XYZ.ID` or `Where ABC.SomeABCColumn = XYZ.SomeXYZColumn` or `Where ABC.ID_OtherTable = XYZ.ID_OtherTable`? getting this straight helps us understand your query. For clarity's sake you could also explicitely tell us what the tables' primary keys are and how the tables are related.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this subquery using indexes:

```
SELECT (Select Top 1 Column
        From ABC
        Where ABC.ID = XYZ.ID
        Order By ABC.ID DESC
       )
FROM XYZ
```

You want the index `ABC(ID DESC, column)`.  Assuming the query is the more reasonable:

```
SELECT (Select Top 1 Column
        From ABC
        Where ABC.XYZ_ID = XYZ.ID
------------------^
        Order By ABC.ID DESC
       )
FROM XYZ
```

Then the index would be `ABC(XYZ_ID, ID DESC, COLUMN)`.